# mysql lost table product_attribute_groups

Tags: mysql

One of my table recently disappeard!

When I run: "show tables", the 'product_attribute_groups' is listed, but when I run "select * from product_attribute_groups" mysql return the error: "#1146 - Table 'product_attribute_groups' doesn't exist"

I tried to dump my db, mysql return the error: "1146: Table 'product_attribute_groups' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES"

Please help me to recover this table and backup my db.

Comment: i had the same - "lower_case_table_names" was the reason

Comment: eggyal: InnoDB (Mysql 5.6.12-2). How did you fix that, jaczes? please tell me more detail

Comment: run "SHOW VARIABLES": lower_case_table_names 0

Answer (score 2):

*table created in uppercase, set lower_case_table_names as per your application requirement.

*table is corrupt, repair the table.

if all above points are ok then use **--skip-lock-tables** parameter with mysqldump.

I am sure this will resolve the error.

Comment: "repair table product_attribute_groups" | db_giaonhan.product_attribute_groups | repair | Error    | Table 'db_giaonhan.product_attribute_groups' doesn't exist |
| db_giaonhan.product_attribute_groups | repair | status   | Operation failed

Comment: ..check if you are working with right permissions on table.  use command to check if table exist " mysqlcheck -u mysql_username -p database_name"

This will check and repair any database and tables fed to it. However, if this doesn't work tell me mysql engine and did you ported ur database?

Comment: my db has 168 tables, mysqlcheck -u mysql_username -p database_name print out OK for all tables, excepts product_attributes_groups (table doesn't exist. status   : Operation failed). The server is Centos 5.8 running MySQL Community Server 5.6.12-1, Innodb engine. I tried to dump my db, mysql return the error: "1146: Table 'db_giaonhan.product_attribute_groups' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES"

Comment: if you have restore or ported or your db from some where else , then might be it is corrupted   check these  "INNODB_LOCKS" and "TABLES" table in db "information_schema" b/c "information_schema" is mysql internal db that store information about mysql db tables and privelleges etc.